How should I do to solve this problem, 'Missing output files' error from snakemake?
I'm trying to manage my workflow by using 'snakemake'.
At first, I wrote short 'Snakefile', below, but it didn't run with 'Message'.
I thought this is very simple problem to fix, but I cannot.
What should I do?
Dependencies:
python = 3.10
nakemake = 7.32
Snakefile
Bam $ cat Snakefile
rule A:
        input:
                i = 'B1477.all_merged_3split_dedupped_sorted.bam'
        output:
                o = 'B1477.all_merged_3split_dedupped_sorted2.bam'
        shell:
                "samtools view {input.i} > {output.o}"

Message
Building DAG of jobs...
Job stats:
job      count
-----  -------
A            1
total        1


[Tue Apr  2 19:31:43 2024]
rule A:
    input: B1477.all_merged_3split_dedupped_sorted.bam
    output: B1477.all_merged_3split_dedupped_sorted2.bam
    jobid: 0
    reason: Missing output files: B1477.all_merged_3split_dedupped_sorted2.bam
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

samtools view B1477.all_merged_3split_dedupped_sorted.bam > B1477.all_merged_3split_dedupped_sorted2.bam
Job stats:
job      count
-----  -------
A            1
total        1

Reasons:
    (check individual jobs above for details)
    missing output files:
        A

This was a dry-run (flag -n). The order of jobs does not reflect the order of execution.


How did you try to run it. Your output looks like a dry run snakemake -n. What is your output for snakemake --cores 1

WAIT! That 'message' is just telling you the reason it is running the rule. The reason is because you have an input file and no matching output file yet. And so Snakemake runs the rule. It is a good thing! Feedback is nice. It is a newer feature because you'll see where I used Snakemake 7.3.8 here for a simplified version of your Snakefile, it didn't show that. Here is my simplified version of your Snakefile (without samtools involvement`)...

 run with versions matching yours, namely Snakemake version 7.32.4 with Python 3.10.12. (I had to do pip3 install pulp==2.7.0 according to this issue here to even get snakemake 7.32.4 to work in sessions launched from here that had specified Python 3.10.) You'll see that I get the reason reason: Missing output files: B1477.all_merged_3split_dedupped_sorted2.bam at the same time the rule runs and makes the output as it should.

@keKs I forgot how did I run my snakefile.
'snakemake -np'
As you expected, I executed the script with option -n and -p.

@kEks I follow your solution, snakemake --cored 1 then the script work and I obtained B1477.all_merged_3split_dedupped_sorted2.bam!
But still reason: Missing output files: B1477.all_merged_3split_dedupped_sorted2.bam message is appeared.

Yes, you'll still see reason: Missing output files: B1477.all_merged_3split_dedupped_sorted2.bam  message because snakemake is telling you the exact reason it ran the rule after evaluating the situation prior to running the process directed by the rule.  It is just letting you know why it ran the rule to then make the file your rule specified. The output the rule specified was missing before it ran the rule and so it ran the rule. It is just feedback.

TL;DR:
That is a feature and not an error.
Details
Nowhere in anything you shared is there an actual error or exception. (You can even search the text and you don't see 'error' there.)
That 'message' is just telling you the reason it is running the rule.
The reason is because you have an input file and no matching output file yet. And so Snakemake runs the rule.
It is a good thing! Feedback is nice.
Here is my simplified version of your Snakefile, without samtools involvement, run with versions matching yours, namely Snakemake version 7.32.4 with Python 3.10.12. (I had to do pip install pulp==2.7.0 according to this issue here to even get snakemake 7.32.4 to work in sessions launched from here that had specified Python 3.10.)
You'll see that I get the reason starment there,reason: Missing output files: B1477.all_merged_3split_dedupped_sorted2.bam, at the same time the rule runs and makes the output as it should. I listed the files before and after to illustrate there.
The reason: message is a newer feature because you'll see where I used Snakemake 7.3.8 here for a simplified version of your Snakefile, it didn't show that.

Oh, I forgot how do I run the script.
snakemake -np
The linux command above is what I run.
Thank you for the detailed and kind answer!

From in the documentation here: "Since we used the -n (or --dry-run) flag, Snakemake will only show the execution plan instead of actually performing the steps. The -p flag instructs Snakemake to also print the resulting shell command for illustration." Those are the two flags you have there. You don't want the n in there, like @kEks comment was trying to advise you. Like @kEks said, you can run snakemake --cores 1 -p to run it. You don't want the dry-run flag. Note I don't use it in the demo notebooks I link , with the ...

 exception where I specifically say I am trying it just to see what snakemake says during that. I already showed how to run snakemake twice in each notebook before trying that.

Thank you. Through this QnA, I understood how to handle snakemake.
